# Automatically supply input for every prompt in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

I have a bash script that logs into multiple nodes using ssh. For every node, it's asking me for the login password, but the password is the same for the same user on all nodes. Is there a way to programatically provide the password every time the password prompt pops up?

Comment: Look into `expect`

Comment: Use ssh keys, they are designed especially for that.

Comment: Only if you can't use keys, then check out: `man sshpass`

Comment: Or something like [`sexpect`](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/)?

Comment: @Ivan, i'm precisely doing this to append my SSH keys!

Comment: @user1934428, that's a funky name for a program.

Comment: Indeed, and it makes it difficult to google this tool by name. Perhaps _shellexpect_ would have been a bit clearer. Well, this is what we get when we try to abbreviate at all cost...

Answer (score 0):

You should put your ssh key in the /.ssh/authorized_keys file its the best way to do this.
Note that write the login and password in your script is dangerous

If you need to generate the ssh key use ssh-keygen

Comment: this is only a temporary approach while i'm actually appending my SSH keys using the script.

Comment: In this case you can use ```#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@host
expect "assword:"
send "passwd\r"
interact```